# Is this kind of optimization a compiler bug or not?

Tags: c++, multithreading, visual-c++, c++11, clang

Declarations: I use vs 2010/vs 2013, and clang 3.4 prebuilt binary.

I've found a bug in our production code. I minimize the reproduce code to the following:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;

bool s_begin_init =  false;
bool s_init_done =  false;

void thread_proc(void * arg)
{
    DWORD tid = GetCurrentThreadId();
    printf("Begin Thread %2d, TID=%u\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(arg), tid);
    if (!s_begin_init)
    {
        s_begin_init = true;
        Sleep(20);
        s_init_done = true;
    }
    else
    {
        while(!s_init_done) { ; }
    }
    printf("End   Thread %2d, TID=%u\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(arg), tid);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    argc = argc                       ; argv = argv                       ; 
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; ++i)
    {
        _beginthread(thread_proc, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(i));
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile and run the code:
cl /O2 /Zi /Favc.asm vc_O2_bug.cpp   && vc_O2_bug.exe

Some of the threads are busying in the while loop. By checking the produced assembly code, I found the assembly code of

> while(!s_init_done) {; }

is:

```
; Line 19
    mov al, BYTE PTR ?s_init_done@@3_NA     ; s_init_done
$LL2@thread_pro:
; Line 21
    test    al, al
    je  SHORT $LL2@thread_pro
; Line 23
```

It's obvious that when use -O2 optimization flag, VC copy the s_init_done to al register, and repeatedly test the al register.

I then use the clang-cl.exe  compiler driver to test the code. The result is same, and the assembly code are
equivalent.

It looks that the compiler think that variable s_init_done will never be changed because the only statement which change it's value is in the "if" block, which is exclusive with the current "else" branch.

I tried the same code with VS2013, The result is also same.

What I doubt is: In C++98/C++03 standard, there's no concept of thread. So the compiler can perform such an optimization for a single-thread-machine. But since c++11 has thread, and both clang 3.4 and VC2013 have support C++11 well, do my question is:

Is think kind of optimization a compiler bug for C++98/C++03, and for C++11 separately?

BTW: When I use -O1 instead, or add volatile qualifier to s_init_done, the bug disappeared.

Comment: That's not a compiler bug, there's nothing in your program which forces the compiler not to optimize away the static variable load according to the standard.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious: Are you really sure that is enough according to the standard?

Comment: @Deduplicator MSVC gives acquire-release semantics to `volatile`; it's a non-standard extension. The standard fix to the data race is to make `s_begin_init` and `s_init_done` into `std::atomic<bool>`.

Comment: @Deduplicator To force a reload yes but it doesn't address the race condition.

Comment: You also technically have undefined behavior in your `printf` format strings, `DWORD` is `typedef`ed as `unsigned long` and requires `%lu`.

Comment: @user657267 For MSVC on Intel 32/64, `unsigned long` has the same representation as `unsigned`. I believe the use of `%lu` is therefore implementation defined, but certainly non-portable.

Comment: @user657267 Err, I mean the use of `%u` in place of `%lu`.

Comment: @Casey Well no sane compiler would do anything funny if the underlying representations are the same, but surely it's still undefined as `unsigned` and `unsigned long` are distinct types, and a compiler could legitimately print garbage if it wanted to in this case.

Comment: @user657267 A standard-compliant compiler *could* do anything - the standard does not define the behavior - but MSVC on Intel *does* define the behavior. Hence my claim the behavior is "implementation-defined." A program that's using a non-portable type like `DWORD` is already implementation-specific, so it's no great loss to rely on further implementation-specific behavior.

Comment: @Casey thanks that makes sense, according to [MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hf4y5e3w.aspx) "By default, unless they are modified by a size field length prefix, integer arguments are coerced to `int` type". They don't mention what happens with `unsigned` types without a size specifier although I suppose they meant to say that values are coerced to either `int` or `unsigned int` according to the flag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your program contains data races on `s_begin_init` and `s_init_done`, and therefore has undefined behavior. Per C++11 §1.10/21:

> The execution of a program contains a *data race* if it contains two conflicting actions in different threads, at least one of which is not atomic, and neither happens before the other. Any such data race results in undefined behavior.

The fix is to declare both boolean variables to be atomic:

```
std::atomic<bool> s_begin_init{false};
std::atomic<bool> s_init_done{false};
```

or to synchronize accesses to them with a `mutex` (I'll throw in a condition variable to avoid busy-waiting):

```
std::mutex mtx;
std::condition_variable cvar;
bool s_begin_init = false;
bool s_init_done = false;

void thread_proc(void * arg)
{
    DWORD tid = GetCurrentThreadId();
    printf("Begin Thread %2d, TID=%u\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(arg), tid);
    std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
    if (!s_begin_init)
    {
        s_begin_init = true;
        lock.unlock();
        Sleep(20);
        lock.lock();
        s_init_done = true;
        cvar.notify_all();
    }
    else
    {
        while(!s_init_done) { cvar.wait(lock); }
    }
    printf("End   Thread %2d, TID=%u\n", reinterpret_cast<int>(arg), tid);
}
```

EDIT: I just noticed the mention of VS2010 in the OP. [VS2010 does not support C++11 atomics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx), so you will have to use the `mutex` solution or take advantage of [MSVC's non-standard extension that gives `volatile` variables acquire-release semantics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a04hfd.aspx):

```
volatile bool s_begin_init = false;
volatile bool s_init_done = false;
```